# Handling MongoDB fields which are strings and treating as numerics

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a field stored in Mongo which is stored as a string, but most of the time it contains a number, but if that number doesn't exist it comprises 'N/A' string for example. I'm using PyMongo and looking for an effective way to perform a less-than and greater-than query, but obviously I do not want to do a comparison as string.

Here is what I have:

```
{"field": '5.6'} 
{"field": 'N/A'}

results = mongo.db.validated.find({"field": "$gt": float(minimum)}, "field": {"$lt": float(maximum)}})
```

So I would like to pick out values that like between `minimum` and `maximum` but ignore `'N/A'`.

Comment: Is 5.6 stored as {field:5.6} or {field:"5.6"}?

Answer (score 1):

You may add a [type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) checking to query like this:

```
results = mongo.db.validated.find({"field": {"$type": 1, "$gt": float(minimum),"$lt": float(maximum)}})
```

***$type:1*** will return double datatypes.

Comment: Hmm, I gave this a shot, but not returning any results. I even took about the implicit AND along with the float(), but its not returning any results.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Since the number value is also stored as string you cannot use the above approach. In such case you need to use regex queries. But keep in mind that it would be very slow. Sample: db.validated.find("this.field >= 5.6 && this.field <= 10")